# Integral of Constant Parameter Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

What is the $\int_{1}^{t}W_1W_sdW_s$. This is the question solved by Kuo in his paper an extension of the Ito's Integral (2008) but there limit runs from $0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Using the definition of the Itô integral, it is not difficult to show that $$\int_1^t W_1 W_s \, dW_s = W_1 \int_1^t W_s \, dW_s.$$

Comment: What is the argument for this step. I would like to add that after this step one can apply the Ito's formula to get the final result. I am confused about the only step which you have stated. Please provide an explanation to your step.

Comment: By definition, the Itô integral $$\int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$$ is the $L^2$-limit of sums of the form $$\sum_{j=0}^n f(t_j) (W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_j})$$ where $0=t_0 < \ldots < t_n \leq t$ is a partition of the interval $[0,t]$. Use this result in order to show the equality stated in my previous comment.